# Prevent dropdown from automatically reopening on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile-development

I have a drop down list as follows:

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <button className="nav-btn pick-a-sort">PICK A SORT:</button>
    <div className = "dropdown-content">
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "bubble-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.bubbleSort()}}>BUBBLE SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "selection-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.selectionSort()}}>SELECTION SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "insertion-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.insertionSort()}}>INSERTION SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "quick-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.quickSort()}}>QUICK SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "merge-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.mergeSort()}}>MERGE SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "bead-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.beadSort()}}>BEAD SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "heap-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.heapSort()}}>HEAP SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "radix-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.radixSort()}}>RADIX SORT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set the CSS such that once any of the options is clicked, the dropdown automatically hides till the specific task is complete (sorting) by adding the class '.clicked' to the dropdown. Once the task is complete I remove the '.clicked' class.

This is working great on desktop site but on the mobile site, once the task is complete, the dropdown reopens automatically, and I'm not exactly why.

Here's my CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .nav-btn{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown.clicked:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the live [website](https://roy-05.github.io/sort-visualizer/) where you can see the problem, by just switching the view to "mobile" and clicking on any algorithm under "PICK A SORT:"

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your live website mentioned, after going through your code 
in `SortingVisualizer.js` in `componentDidUpdate()` I see it in `line number 61`
you are calling `this.showDropdown()` which after component update is opening the dropdown again.

Well after seeing your js code I was wondering why were you removing .clicked class, as that enabled the dropdown to hide(making display:none) and why did you not do it on button click rather chose to do it on a lifeCycle,

add a click event on "PICK A SORT" button like this and remove `this.showDropdown()` in `componentDidUpdate()`

```
<button className="nav-btn pick-a-sort" onClick={this.showDropdown}>PICK A SORT:</button>
```

Comment: I might expect a question on how on earth did i know your components name, its because I have react devtools installed and I was able to see your code from it

Comment: So showDropdown() is simply removing the clicked class  -


    showDropdown(){
        const dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
        
        dropdown.className = "dropdown";
    }


That seemed to be working for desktop and doesnt reopen the dropdown there. But I figure that might be because the pseudo-class is set to hover?

Comment: why does your hideDropdown() add a clicked class... isn't it to hide?

Comment: so now its working fine???... you don't have to put the code here I can see it :)

Comment: I guess it is poor classNaming but if you look at the 'clicked' class it is changing display to 'none'

Comment: no, it still displays the dropdown, I think it might be because in the mobile site the "PICK A SORT" button is still in focus after sort completion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203338/discussion-between-sri-venkata-pavan-kumar-mhs-and-roy05).